# Rollup use relative paths to support file:///

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, static-site

Currently I am writing a static svelte SPA, and I am using Rollup to bundle everything. However, I want to make it so that the final `index.html` file can be opened as a file (i.e. double-clicking it on windows explorer). When I try to do so currently, since Rollup uses paths relative to the root of the "domain", it fails to loads:
[image: console errors screenshot]

Being very clueless at Rollup config, is there a way for me to switch all of the URLs to use relative paths (i.e. `./global.css` etc) to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
export default defineConfig({
  base: '', // or './'
})
```

in your vite.config.js file